# PyQt QWidget window closes immediately upon showing?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qt4

I realize that this question has been asking several times before, though none of them seem to apply to my situation. I have installed PyQt, and am simply trying to open up a window as such:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui as qt

segmentation = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = qt.QWidget()
main.show()
```

All the other questions I have looked at on here usually were caused by an error with the window going out of scope because of the window's `show` method being called from within a function, or something similar.

My code uses no functions at all so this cannot be the issue. This should work as it is, no? I am following this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBME1ZyHiP8

and at time 8:58, the instructor has pretty much exactly what I have written, and their window shows up and stays around just fine. Mine displays for a fraction of a second and then closes.

Screen shot of the code block from the video to compare to the code block provided here:

[image: Demo code that works]

Comment: Look at the video. The demo does not have the `.exec_()` code. Other than variable names, the code posted by the OP is the same. The question is why does it work there, but not when the OP runs it.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the video for those that do not wish to navigate to the moment mentioned by the OP. This shows that the code is similar (variable names are different), but that the window stays open in the demo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without seeing all of your code, I'm assuming that you're missing the `sys.exit()` bit.

For your specific code `sys.exit(segmentation.exec_())` would be what you needed.

```
segmentation = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = qt.QWidget()
main.show()
sys.exit(segmentation.exec_())
```

---

A little bit of detail of what's going on here.

`segmentation = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)` creates the actual application.

`main = qt.QWidget()` and `main.show()` creates the Widget and then displays.

When executing the python script, this does exactly what you tell it to:

1. Create an application
2. Create a widget
3. Show the widget
4. Finished.  End of the script.

What the `sys.exit()` does is cleanly closes the python script.  `segmentation.exec_()` starts the event driven background processing of QT.  Once the `segementation.exec_()` is finished (user closes the application, your software closes the application, or a bug is encountered) it'll return a value which is then passed into the `sys.exit()` function which in turn terminates the python process.

Comment: Look at the video. The demo does not have the `.exec_()` code. Other than variable names, the code posted by the OP is the same.

Comment: @jphollowed, This answer is correct though. Adding the line of code provided here will prevent the window from closing.

Comment: This is literally all of my code. I have just started the tutorial and only have gotten this far before this went wrong. If you look at 8:58 in the video linked, my exact code works for him. I have just tried what you suggest, and it does fix the issue. But I still wonder why `sys.exit` was not required in the video, but required for me. Thanks.

Comment: @jphollowed I'm going to assume that the video is showing an interactive experience.  Meaning the code executed isn't actually terminated like a normal script is run.  If you were to execute your code in an iPython console, the window would appear and not immediately close.

Comment: Thank you for adding an explanation, this makes perfect sense.